# Windows certificate viewing, why 2048-bit certificate shown as 270 byte?

Tags: certificate

I'm a bit confused by how Windows certificate viewer displays public key hexdump.

Windows shows 270 bytes for a 2048-bit public key(which is 256 byte). While Firefox 31 display right 256 bytes. And I notice the hexdump values are different.

The certificate I view is "DigiCert Global Root CA" with serial 083BE056904246B1A1756AC95991C74A .

Can someone help explain this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificates are the same. Microsoft add padding information before and after the certificate, see the picture

[image: padding]

Comment: Thank you. You're right. Could you tell me what do those 14 padding bytes mean, a reference link is welcome.

Comment: @JimmChen, honestly I have no idea. But from what i dig the last 3 bytes are the exponent (in this case "Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)". If I find additional info will update you